# (eval '(* a b)) return a final result rather than an intermediate (* 2 3)

Tags: scheme, sicp

In [4.1.3  Evaluator Data Structures of SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-26.html#%_sec_4.1.3), it states:

> That the user's programs are the evaluator's data need not be a source
>   of confusion. In fact, it is sometimes convenient to ignore this
>   distinction, and to give the user the ability to explicitly evaluate a
>   data object as a Lisp expression, by making **eval** available for use
>   in programs. Many Lisp dialects provide a primitive **eval** procedure
>   that takes as arguments an expression and an environment and evaluates
>   the expression relative to the environment.

Then experiment with

```
Chez Scheme Version 9.5
Copyright 1984-2017 Cisco Systems, Inc.

> (define a 5)
> (define b 6)
> (eval '(* a b))
30
```

I think the result not make sense, since it does both eval and apply.

As I learned from the proceeding contents, I predict the result should be

```
> (eval '(* a b))
  '(* (5 6))
```

Then apply * to list-of-values (5 6).

Eval produce value of arguments and procedures to be applied rather than a final result.

Am I wrong with the understanding of eval?

Comment: Application is part of evaluation. `(* a b)` by itself evaluates to 30, not `(* 5 6)`.

Comment: `eval`ing an expression evaluates it completely.

Comment: To get `(* 2 3)`: `(eval ''(* 2 3))`. Notice the double quoting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically what happens with `(eval '(* a b))` under the hood is as you describe. Since `*` is not a special form or macro it evaluates it to the procedure object, then it evaluates `a` and `b` and it then applies the procedure it got from evaluating `*` with the list of evaluated arguments. It does not stop half way so you get the full evaluation.

Also know that `*` is a variable. The procedure behind it you can see by evaluating `*`by itself. It would not have shown `*`.